# Can I limit hours of access to an Azure site?

Tags: azure

Is there any easy way to limit the availability of an Azure static website to eg office hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define 'easy'.  If easy means inside an Azure Static website does this functionality exist, the answer is no.  There are ways to accomplish this but you need something outside of Azure Static Website to accomplish the scheduling part.  One path to consider.

1. You could, on a schedule, replace the current site with an 'off-hour' site that might just have a index.html (could be an image of a closed sign).
2. Github actions can be scheduled see [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows)

Another option is to schedule the deletion/recreation of the static site using either Azure Automation or my personal favorite, Azure Logic Apps.  Depending on the size and complexity of the static site, this might be a show-stopper.

Comment: Easy = inside an Azure Static website does this functionality exist ;) very helpful answer, thanks.